# Django: Change form requirement dynamically, according to another form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a little problem with Django forms. Basically, I have 2 forms, one is a free term search, the others are some filters. The field of the term should be required only if no filters are selected by the user.
I have something like this (but with more filters in the same Class):

```
    class Term(forms.Form):
            terms = forms.CharField(
            label='Term',
            required=True, # but false if the filters is selected
            error_messages={'required': 'Please enter at least one search term'},
            widget=TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'textEntry',
            'placeholder': 'Enter search'}))

    class Filter(forms.Form):
            filter = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            choices = [1,2, 3],
            label = "Filter",
            required = False)
```

I searched everywhere but I found no results. Do you have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass `filter` to your Term form when you instantiate it, then set the value of required for `terms` appropriately. I've modified the names slightly to be more distinguishable for your form classes.

```
# forms.py
class TermForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        filter = kwargs.pop('filter', None)
        super(self, TermForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if filter:
            self.fields['terms'].error_messages = {
                'required': 'Please enter at least one search term'
            }
        else:
            self.fields['terms'].required = False

    terms = forms.CharField(
        label='Term',
        widget=TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'textEntry',
            'placeholder': 'Enter search'}))

# views.py, assuming Django 1.4.x+
from django.shortcuts import render
from your_app.forms import TermForm, FilterForm

def a_view(request):
    filter_form = FilterForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and filter_form.is_valid():
        term_form = TermForm(request.POST or None,
            filter_form.cleaned_data.get('filter')
        if term_form.is_valid():
            # do something

    return render(request, 'a-template.html',
        {'filter_form': filter_form, 'term_form': term_form})
```

All fields are automatically required, unless you specifically set them not to be, which is why the logic in the `__init__` override might seem backwards. If you need to visually indicate that the field is required when a `filter` is chosen, you'll need to add some JavaScript to do so.